# C# split, return key/value pairs in an array

Tags: c#, database, split

I'm new to C#, and thus am looking for layman's terms regarding this.  Essentially, what I would like to do is turn:

key1=val1|key2=val2|...|keyN=valN

into a database array where, you guessed it, key1 returns val1, key2 returns val2, etc.  I know I could return a string using split, but from that point on, I'm at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I hope I've made my intentions clear, but if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: @Mark Byers: I am assuming he meant "associative array" like a dictionary.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
string s = "key1=val1|key2=val2|keyN=valN";
var dict = s.Split('|')
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Now `dict` is a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the desired key/value pairs.

Comment: This helps me immensely.  As I said, I'm new to C#, and working on my first program as an add-on (more or less) to a program I already use.  Thank you!

Comment: that's an awesome use of closures, nice!

Comment: Added exception handling.      string s = "key1=val1|key2=val2|keyN=valN";
            var dict = s.Split('|')
                        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                         .Where(x => x.Length > 1 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[0].Trim()) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[1].Trim()))
                         .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());

Answer (score 9):

```
Dictionary<string,string> results = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(string kvp in source.split('|'))
{
    results.Add(kvp.split('=')[0], kvp.split('=')[1]);
}
```

Probably a Linq way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 string s = "key1=val1|key2=val2|keyN=valN";
 var dict = s.Split('|')
 .Select(x => x.Split('='))
 .Where(x => x.Length > 1 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[0].Trim())
  && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[1].Trim()))
 .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
```

Comment: this is beautiful; any idea how to convert this so that handles duplicate values? i.e. to keep the latest value if a duplicate has been found.

Comment: Try this var
`values = (item.Split(',')
                  .Select(p => new { p, splittedP = p.Split('=') })
                  .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.splittedP[0], p.splittedP[1])))
                  .ToList();`